# Google Analytics Bounce Rate Under 100% on a Single Page Site

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, bounce

Google describes it's bounce rate metric thusly:

> Bounce rate is the percentage of
>   single-page visits or visits in which
>   the person left your site from the
>   entrance (landing) page.

[My site](http://mildfuzz.com) is essentially a single page, with no outbound links. Why, then, is my bounce rate NOT 100%, in fact, it is roughly 60%!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics considers *any* session with more than 1 hit sent to its servers as a non-bounce visit; it doesn't distinguish between unique and non-unique pageviews.

Thus, if someone views your 1-page website twice (ie, refreshes the page, submits a form, etc); anything that triggers any pageviews or google analytics events, it will consider the visit a non-bounce visit.

That indicates that roughly 40% of your visitors are interacting with the site beyond a single pageview.

(If you were doing some sort of external link tracking, then people clicking the Twitter and Facebook links would send a second hit and would be treated as non-bouncers; however, this does not appear to be the case, so that is not the cause of the lower-than-expected bounce rate).

Comment: @yahelc I have a bounce-rate of 95% but 10% visitors are returning. Shouldn't the bounce-rate be 90%, if your answer is correct?

Comment: There's no relationship between bounce rate and whether or not someone is a returning visitor, @Tyilo. "Returning visitor" means they've had a visit in the past (say, 3 months ago). A non-bounce visit means their visit had more than one hit in it.

All your data means, on a single page site, is "One in twenty of my visitors refreshed my page within their 30 minute visit. Unrelatedly, one in ten of my visitors had visited in the past."

Comment: @yahelc You didn't mention 30 minutes before and I didn't know it. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Our bounce rate went from 45% to 99% when we changed our landing page for one that looks like yours, we managed to get back to 50% after we changed the layout for something more simple, without jQuery show/hide divs. And you have 2 links facebook and twitter.